# Set default image for all posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code to have the Featured Image set on all Pages as a banner, in the header. So all pages have different banners:

```
<img src="<?php $imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) , 'full'); echo $imgsrc[0]; ?>" class="middle" alt="banner">
```

I don't want to use this for Posts because I need to set different small pics there. I need a way to automatically have all Posts use a default image banner that wouldn't take the spot of the Featured Image that I need freed up.
Is there a way to auto detect that it's a Post page and have that default image instead?

Tried everything I could find on search engines, but I can't figure out.

Answer (score 2):

One solution (if you use the same template for posts and pages) is to use the function [`get_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) to check the post type:

```
if( 'post' == get_post_type() ) {
    // load image for posts
} else {
    // image for pages
}
```

Another solution is to use a template for posts (like `single.php`, or `single-post.php` if you have other custom post types) and one for pages (`page.php`), so you can use different code on different post types.

Comment: It doesnt matter which template i use. Any would pull the header.php and there is the code <img src="<?php $imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) , 'full'); echo $imgsrc[0]; ?>" class="middle" alt="banner">    Need something here changed to pull the Featured image if its a Page and pull a default image i set the path to if its a Post. Hope i explained better this time, thanks alot for trying to help!

Comment: So maybe use the first solution?